# Odoo adding messages in oe_chatter

Tags: odoo, qweb

I'm developing in Odoo Qweb and I need to add some messages in oe_chatter box when some events are thrown.
Those messages had to be written in the next class: "calendar_event".
Those are the records for written the messages:

```
@http.route('/events_accept/all/<int:meeting_id>', type='http', auth="user",website=True)
def meetings(self,meeting_id=None):
 event = request.env['calendar.event'].search([('id', '=', meeting_id)])
 msg_body = "....."
 #Write messages in oe_chatter
```

Anyone knows how to do this task?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be enough to call `message_post()` on `calendar.event` recordsets.

```py
event = request.env['calendar.event'].search([('id', '=', meeting_id)])
msg_body = "....."
event.message_post(body=msg_body)
```

If you want to use subtypes or other features of chatter messages look into `message_post()` to understand its possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it worked! Do you know if using "message_post" function, all of the follower users of the recordset are noticed? @CZoellner

Comment: Yes a simple `message_post()` should notice all followers, but you can use the method to post internal messages to, where nobody will be noticed.